# "以" in "敗義以求生， 豈荀巨伯所行邪"

Tags: meaning-in-context, preposition

Does "以" have the same meaning in the following sentences?

> 敗義**以**求生， 豈荀巨伯所行邪

> 志士仁人 無求生**以**害仁

Comment: yes, the "以" has the same usage in these two verses.

Answer (score 2):

> in "敗義[**以**]求生， 豈荀巨伯所行邪",  '以' functions as  "to" in English
>
> commit immoral act [**to**] survive, isn't something I (荀巨伯) would do
>
> *it makes no sense to interpret  it as "commit immoral act with attempt of surviving"*

~

> in "志士仁人 無求生[**以**]害仁", '以' functions as "with" or "by" in English
>
> principled and kind person, would not try to survive **with** immoral act
>
> principled and kind person, would not try to survive **by** committing immoral act
>
> *it makes no sense to interpret  it as "trying to survive to commit immoral act"*